# Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb"

Tags: qt

I'm using xubuntu 18.04(Linux 4.15.0-48-generic x86_64
)(buildd@lgw01-amd64-036) (gcc version 7.3.0 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)) #51-Ubuntu SMP), 
after installing anki as shown on anki's web:

```
$ tar xjf Downloads/anki-2.1.12-amd64.tar.bz2
$ cd anki-2.1.12-linux-amd64
$ sudo make install
```

I got this message when I run anki:

> qt: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it
>   was found. qt: This application failed to start because no Qt platform
>   plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this
>   problem.
>
> Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl,
>   offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl,
>   wayland-xcomposite-glx, xcb.
>
> [1]    3022 abort (core dumped)  anki

Even after reinstalling it, or restarting my machine.

Comment: Is that the only Qt application that fails?  What about the demo programs of Qt (in the `qtbase5-examples` package)?

Answer (score 3):

With Xubuntu 18.04, you have (2) options to install **anki** without going through the trouble of compiling it yourself:

1. From the Ubuntu repos: `sudo apt install anki` (version 2.1.0)
2. From Flatpak: `flatpak install flathub net.ankiweb.Anki` (version 2.1.13)

Answer (score 3):

Try:
 Going to your platforms directory and performing, `ldd libqxcb.so`. Make sure that all the dependencys listed are installed and that they are in your collection of shared librarys. If not install or place them in your shared libs.

Answer (score 1):

Try reinstalling libxcb:

```
sudo apt purge libxcb
sudo apt install libxcb
```

If the package is not found use this:

```
sudo apt purge libxcb1
sudo apt install libxcb1
```

More info about the packages: `https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/bionic/libxcb`

Also, post the output of `ldd /usr/lib/qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so`

Comment: Everyone, DON'T DO THIS unless you're ABSOLUTELY SURE of what your doing! It took me days to recover from half of this uninstall process. I'm not on a Debian-based distro, but my guess is DON'T DO THIS IF YOU USE KDE. `sudo zypper rm libxcb1` is only second to `rm -rf /*` in terms of devastation on openSUSE with KDE. You've been warned. (and yes, I have only myself to blame for mindlessly launching this command)

Comment: I have to say openSUSE is just weird sometimes. Reminds me how I installed Anaconda (now called Conda) and it broke my KDE as well...

Comment: It's not weird. It's just not Debian. Just different  all Linux distro are not the same

Comment: I've used plenty of distros in my life and openSUSE apparently belongs to the weird ones..